# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that index of $H$ and order of $H$ are coprime then $H$ is only subgroup of $G$ of order $O(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I am solving Herstein' Topics in Algebra right now and there I have already proved that if $x$ is an element of $G$ such that $x^{O(H)} = e$ then $x$ belongs to $H$.
Suppose there exists another subgroup $S$ of $G$ of order $O(H)$ then every element of $S$ satisfies $x^{O(H)} = e$ this implies every element of $S$ belongs to $H$ thus $H$ is unique.
Is my approach correct?

Comment: You shall use `$` to wrap around your math expressions so as to improve the readability of your post. You may use `{}` to wrap around the exponents in converting the expressions.

Comment: What you've written is fine. The main part seems to be to show that $x^{O(H)} = e \implies x \in H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is fine. The main crux of the argument however is to show that $x^{|H|} = e \implies x \in H$.
That is where one uses the normality of $H$ and the fact that $|H|$ and $|G|/|H|$ are coprime.

Here's a quick proof: Since $H \unlhd G$, it makes sense to talk about the quotient group $G/H$.
Let $x \in G$ be such that $x^{|H|} = e$. Thus, going modulo $H$, we get $\bar{x}^{|H|} = \bar{e}$. Thus, the order of $\bar{x}$ in $G/H$ divides both $|H|$ and $|G/H|$ and hence, must be $1$. Thus, $\bar{x} = \bar{e}$ or $x \in H$.